# How to parse an escape sequence?

Tags: c#, string, parsing, escaping

I'm writing a parser for my own markup and I need to handle a few escape sequences but I'm not sure which strategy I should choose.

In particular I have two in my mind.

Here's an example `foo \\\<bar baz` with two of them: `\\` and `\<`.

When I now scan the string char by char

1. should I detect the backslash `\` and then check if the next character is an excapable one or
2. should I check for the character and then look back to see whether it's preceded by a backslash `\`?

Are there any *major* (dis)advantages in either one?

Comment: Off the top of my head it would be better to check for a blackslash, because finding all blackslashes vs finding all of every escapable character seems more efficient

Comment: What unescaping are you trying to implement? Lots of different things use backslashes for escaping, but often in different ways.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm experimenting with my own markup and several charachters will have special meaning in a given context. I need a way to escape them.

Comment: Using the first method is simpler to check for double occurrence of your escape character, the second would find the first instance & ignore it, then you would find the second & need to re-read the preceding character - on the third one you would need to know not to look back for a preceding escape char as it has already been processed.

Comment: Write a state machine. A very simple one. When you see a backslash in the unescaped state, switch to the escaped state. When you see a backslash in the escaped state, it's a backslash (or if it's a `t`, it's a tab -- etc. etc.). After interpreting an escaped character, the state goes back to unescaped. This is essentially option #2 but a slightly different way of thinking about it.

Comment: Your question should *state* that you're writing your own markup then. Otherwise "I'm writing a parser" is very, very ambiguous.

Comment: @JonSkeet I improved the question as suggested. I didn't think it would matter. Sorry.

Comment: @EdPlunkett ok, this makes sense and is easier to implement then scannig the string back and forth looking for characters. Then I'll go with the #2.5

Comment: I think there may be another approach you can use.If you create a stack then put escape chars in the input in it, then check every push to stack.if you find the elements in stack are same item you defined , pop it until stack empty.

Comment: @EdPlunkett: Isnt your answer essentially option #1 as you are detecting the escape character first & then checking the next character?

Comment: well, I had never thought that parsing an escape sequence might be classified as _too broad_ and I even get DV for this. I thought I'm asking for something really basic but as I've never done this before I just wanted to be sure which method I should choose, luckily I got some suggestions in comments and there's even another option that I didn'see before. Anyways, thank you :-) I guess this question is on its way to get closed.

Comment: Option 2 I see as potentially error-prone, as it doesn't check for backslashes that precede non-escape characters. That or it assumes that lone backslashes should be interpreted literally, which causes consistency issues with `\\`.

Comment: @PaulF Well, it avoids the "look behind" problem of "OK, the last character was a backslash -- but was it escaped?" So yeah I think you've got a point.

Comment: OP, [here's a quickie one](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PyvysP). Sorry for parser rocking. Not sorry.

Comment: @EdPlunkett you could post this and the previous comment as an answer so that I have something to accept before the question gets closed for apparently being off topic.

Comment: I admit, I didn't think about the more complex escape sequences yet, they are scarry ;-]

Comment: I think however this can be solved with a more complex state, like the stack suggested by @FreeMan where I could store several escape characters

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to know where you're at. The way to do that is a state machine. If you're only doing `\r`, `\t`, `\n`, `\"`, and `\\`, you can get by with a very simple one. Like this ([fiddle here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PyvysP)):

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    private enum UnescapeState
    {
        Unescaped,
        Escaped
    }

    public static String Unescape(this String s)
    {
        var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        UnescapeState state = UnescapeState.Unescaped;

        foreach (var ch in s)
        {
            switch (state)
            {
                case UnescapeState.Escaped:
                    switch (ch)
                    {
                        case 't':
                            sb.Append('\t');
                            break;
                        case 'n':
                            sb.Append('\n');
                            break;
                        case 'r':
                            sb.Append('\r');
                            break;
                        
                        case '\\':
                        case '\"':
                            sb.Append(ch);
                            break;

                        default:
                            throw new Exception("Unrecognized escape sequence '\\" + ch + "'");

                    }
                    state = UnescapeState.Unescaped;
                    break;

                case UnescapeState.Unescaped:
                    if (ch == '\\')
                    {
                        state = UnescapeState.Escaped;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sb.Append(ch);
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }

        if (state == UnescapeState.Escaped)
        {
            throw new Exception("Unterminated escape sequence");
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```